# What is the exact way for view handling in multiple orientation in iPad application development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

What is the best way for view handling in multiple orientations in iPad.

In my understanding and some research,

1. You can handle this in code.
2. You can have two xibs.
3. You can have two view in same xibs, each view is for one orientation.

But I am bit confused on what is the apples recommendation, best way / practice. Kindly reply.

Comment: Apple does recommerate anything, it's up to you. But I would use AutoLayout. Just one view with some constraints and you done for both orientations.

Answer (score 0):

And here is a guide from apple. If autolayout it's not suitable for you, then you need a separate landscape viewcontroller.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html

Comment: Actually I am looking for a industry best practice sort of thing.

Comment: Autolayout is the best option if you don't need advanced stuff. Otherwise, I would recommend "Creating an Alternate Landscape Interface" form the link I sent, you have to be careful with iPhone/IOS6 upsideDown orientation when using this method.